# SQL Case When statement to check if field is in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Apologies in advance if something like this has already come up, but I can't find it.

I have declared a temporary table `@x` which contains a list of IDs.

In my main query I want to check if a particular record `ID` appears in the `@x` table and then return `'Yes'` or `'No'` respectively.

I tried the following case when statement:

```
select (case when xsup_ID in @x then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as Ins
```

But I am getting errors when running it:

> An Expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected

and

> Incorrect syntax near '@x'

is it possible to use the above statement and if not, what would be the best way how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select (case when xsup_ID in (select id from @x) then 'YES' else 'NO' end) as Ins
```

i.e. your IN should be testing against a subquery of one column, instead of the table variable itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when CHARINDEX(xsup_ID ,@x) > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO' end)
```